# R, using 'fPortfolio' package: setting the risk free interest rate

Tags: r, portfolio

I am struggling with the 'fPortfolio' package in R. 
I need to set the risk free interest rate. (obviously I need this for when the sharpe ratio etc are calculated; but an arbitrary risk-free rate of is assumed) 
I have tried:

-Attempt 1

```
Spec = portfolioSpec()[[1]]  
# Change Risk Free Rate
setRiskFreeRate(Spec) = 0.008
Frontier = portfolioFrontier(returns_ts,spec = Spec)
weightsSlider(Frontier)
```

-Attempt 2

```
weightsSlider(Frontier,spec=Spec)
```

-Attempt 3

```
weightsSlider(Frontier,spec=Spec,riskFreeRate = 0.008)
```

-Problem, each time, there is no error produced. In fact, if i call the 'Spec' object it informs me of a 0.08 rf interest rate. HOWEVER; when I look at the sharpe ratio; it is the tangent line to the frontier, drawn from a completely arbitrary target return.

Answer (score 0):

Should work in the following way:

```
portfolioFrontier(returns_ts,`setRiskFreeRate<-'(portfolioSpec(), 0.008))
```